QGIS modeler adding field with a pre-calculated value but doesn't work after first successful try
Using the modeler, I want to add a new column to my layer. The new column will be used as a label and consists of a number and strings: for example "layername" and "length". Both of these columns already exist.
I tried setting the field calculator in the modeler to "pre-calculated value" and added the following expression: "layer" "length" and it gave the desired result.
On the second try, I got error the following error:
Parser error with formula expression ""layer" "length"": 
syntax error, unexpected QUOTED_COLUMN_REF, expecting end of file
Error encountered while running Field calculator

Ideally, I would like to add a 'm' after 'length' since it's meters.
I know how to do this in the normal field calculator but have been unsuccessful in the modeler.

You know that for a label, you can insert an expression instead of an attribute field name? So you don't have to create a new field for labelling only

Yes, but I need that column too. It's for google earth.

"layer" "length" is not a valid syntax. What does the two fields contain? You want to concatenate them? Can you show a screenshot of your attribute table?

"layer" is a string, length is a dezimal number. I tried using concat too but wasn't successful either.

"layer" || ' ' || "length" || 'm'

You can use the expression "layer" || ' ' || "length" || 'm' in your model, see screenshot. Make sure you have set the Result field type to Text (string) and choose a suitable Result field length value.
Also make sure that the Field name does not yet exist, but that the input vector layer contains two fields named layer and length (spelled exactly like that).
The model; when I run it, it creates the third column you can see on the attribute table on the right:


Thank you! This works! I made things more complicated than needed. Have a nice weekend!

You're welcome. As a new user, please be adviced that this site tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235
